# Scroll Appear's In JqGrid Column's Header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here is my **JqGrid Ajax Function:**

```
function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Downloads.aspx/GetDownLoadData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            var item = response.d;
            if (item != null && item != "" && typeof (item) != 'undefined') {

                $("#list").jqGrid({
                    data: JSON.parse(item),
                    datatype: 'local',
                    colNames: ['DownLoad Name', 'Format','Size','Link',''],
                    colModel: [
                    { name: 'DownLoadName', index: 'DownLoadName', width: 200, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: false },
                    { name: 'Format', index: 'Format', width: 150, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: false },
                    { name: 'Size', index: 'Size', width: 150, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: false },
                    { name: 'Link', index: 'Link', width: 150, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: false },
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 145, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: false,hidden:true }
                    ],
                    rowNum: 5,
                    height:'auto',
                    altRows: true,
                    hoverrows:true,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    sortname: 'Id',
                    sortorder: 'asc',
                    caption: "DownLoad Data",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    width:995,
                       loadError: function (xhr) {
                        alert("The Status code:" + xhr.status + " Message:" + xhr.statusText);//Getting reponse 200 ok
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                var result = '<tr align="left"><td>' + "No Record" + '</td></tr>';
                $('#list').empty().append(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

It give's me **perfect output**, but in output,why scroll bar appears in columns headers?I can't figure it out.Kindly help me out.Thanks.
**Here is output:**
[image]

Kindly see the attached image and circle in `Link` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the following additional CSS rule to fix the problem:

```css
.ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

or

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

jqGrid set only `overflow-x: hidden;` on `.ui-jqgrid-hdiv` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L12)). So depends on other CSS rules used it can be that vertical scrollbar will be included. The above CSS role remove it.

Comment: @Oleg..i insert this code in `ui.jqgrid.css`,but it still show's the scroll

Comment: @Oleg...now it work's fine on firefox,but not on Opera

Comment: @MuhammadAli: **Never ever** modify `ui.jqgrid.css` or other file which you don't own. Just insert `<style type="text/css">.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow-y: hidden; }</style>` after `<link ... href="...ui.jqgrid.css"/>`. About the problem with Opera: in which version of Opera the problem exist: in 12.17 or in 24.0.1558.64? Which zoom (100% or more) you use during the test? Do you have the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem? The problem which you describe is **not pure jqGrid problem**. The problem exist only in **combination** of `ui.jqgrid.css` with **other CSS** (which?).

Comment: @Oleg...Thanks for your suggestions,i am using Opera having version 24.0.1558.64.Zoom is set to 100%,if overlap is the case, so i think so,it also appear in firefox,but in firefox it works fine.

Comment: @MuhammadAli: **Do you have the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem?** If you don't have the demo online you can create it in jsfiddle for example. You can get an example like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/35k71pmw/) and modify it to youth. I suppose that you will need to add some CSS. Click on "External Resources" on the left part, paste URL with additional CSS or JS and click "+" to add it. Click "Save" at the end and post the resulting URL. If the problem exist only with data loaded from the server, see http://jsfiddle.net/ntfw57zm/2/ to use "/echo/json/" service.

Comment: @MuhammadAli: If you click on the cell of header with vertical scrollbar, open context menu and then choose "Inspect element" you will see all CSS applied to the element. You will see "user agent stylesheet" here too. Such "normalizing" CSS added by the web browser can makes compatibility problems. To locale *which* CSS rule from "user agent stylesheet" is the origin of your problem one need to examine the demo which reproduces the problem. After the analyse one can add one more CSS role which overwrite the "user agent stylesheet" setting and fixes the problem.

Comment: ,your last comment is really helpful for me,i inspect the element,it has a class `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv`,it does not have code of `overflow-y:hidden`,though i already inserted it in `ui.jqgrid.css`,but it is not shown in during inspection(for Opera),so following your instructions,i put it in style tag and set the `overflow-y` property to hidden,now it is working fine,all credit goes to you @Oleg...Thanks a lot.